# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-grm0q7k2/astroquery

Tags: python

I am trying to install a program called auromat (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/auromat). I am having difficulty with setup.py and C compiler errors. I am a Mac user and i do have Xcode with command line tools so i know i have gcc (4.2.1). But its odd that I can not locate setup.py but i am getting a C compiler error. I would greatly appreciate your suggestions (PS: I did follow some of the recommendations already but none of them seems to work for me).
Here is the error log:

> The C compiler used to compile Python gcc-4.2, and which is normally
>   used to compile C extensions, is not available. You can explicitly
>   specify which compiler to use by setting the CC environment variable,
>   for example:
>
> ```
> CC=gcc python setup.py <command>
> ```
>
> or if you are using MacOS X, you can try:
>
> ```
> CC=clang python setup.py <command>
> ```

---

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   /private/tmp/pip-build-08eydl5s/astroquery